# How to augment more than one image in ImageDataGenerator augmentation?

Tags: python-3.x, image

I want to increase (augment) the number of images that i have (50 images) using ImageDataGeneator.

I found the following code, but it only augments one image per time (one file). I am new to python, so, if there any other easier method to automatically augment the 50 images at once and save the outcome in a new folder

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, 
img_to_array, load_img
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range =15, 
                         width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                         height_shift_range = 0.2,  
                         rescale=1./255, 
                         shear_range=0.2, 
                         zoom_range=0.2, 
                         horizontal_flip = True, 
                         fill_mode = 'nearest', 
                         data_format='channels_last', 
                         brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])

# This is my problem, It loads only one file, and i am searching for an 
automated method to load number of files together and save them in 
another folder. 

img = load_img(r"C:\Users\user 1\Pictures\people_1\1.jpg")

x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir =r'C:\Users\user 
1\Pictures\people_1\preview', save_prefix ='people2', save_format='jpg'):
    i+=1
    if i>10:
        break
```

The expected result from the above code is 10 augmented images extracted from the main file of 1.jpg, while I have another 50 files, I am searching for a quicker method to augment them all in one code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will do the work:

```
dataset=ImageDataGenerator()
generator = dataset.flow_from_directory('/folder/of/photos',target_size=(110,110),save_to_dir='/folder/to/save/photos',class_mode='binary',save_prefix='N',save_format='jpeg',batch_size=10)

for inputs,outputs in generator:
  continue
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @photeesh Hi, Can you share full code, i have tried but it's not working for me . Suppose my source image folder is Data and where i want to save images be Aug_Data

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a loop to analyze each image. It will be looking at one image per time, but you'll need to execute the code only once.
Firstly you can use the Python method *os.listdir()*. This method will return all names of archives and the respective extension.
After you can construct a loop so that all the names will have been read. 
Take a look:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, 
img_to_array, load_img
import os

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range =15, 
                     width_shift_range = 0.2, 
                     height_shift_range = 0.2,  
                     rescale=1./255, 
                     shear_range=0.2, 
                     zoom_range=0.2, 
                     horizontal_flip = True, 
                     fill_mode = 'nearest', 
                     data_format='channels_last', 
                     brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5]) 

imgs = os.listdir(<path_50_imgs>)

for img in imgs:
    img=cv2.imread(<path_50_imgs>+"\\"+img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

    i = 0
    for batch in datagen.flow (x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir =r'C:\\Users\\user1\\Pictures\\people_1\\preview', save_prefix ='people2', save_format='jpg'):
        i+=1
        if i>10:
            break
```